# Material applied to specific object remains black

Tags: materials

I have created this custom model from a single vertex and this seems to be causing issues when I apply a material to it.

Additionally, I have checked the normals and they seem to be facing the correct direction, so I'm a little confused.

[image: Material not working]

[image: Edit mode of first image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please pack your image (File > External Data >Pack Resources) and share your file?

Answer (score 0):

The *Texture Coordinate* of your material use its *UV* output but your object has no UVs, you need to create some seams and unwrap

Comment: Thanks so much Moonboots, gonna give it a try later today.  Thanks again <3.